# Can't install apk via adb, file DNE despite showing up using adb shell ls

Tags: android, adb

I uploaded an apk using adb

```
adb push myAppName.apk /sdcard/
```

to double check:

```
adb shell ls /sdcard/
```

sure enough, it's there. 
then:

```
adb install /sdcard/myAppName.apk
can't find '/sdcard/myAppName.apk' to install
```

Note* I tried adding the path in parentheses as suggested on an [xda post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=870571) but this didn't help. 
Are there multiple sdcard directories where push defaults to one and install defaults to another? I tried using root explorer to find the files that `adb install /sdcard/<TAB>` suggests but I can't file these files in any dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adb install takes a file on your pc to install it.  It doesn't look on the phone.

Comment: Indeed, this works. I read the adb docs a couple times "You can use adb to copy an application from your development computer and install it on an emulator/device instance. To do so, use the install command. With the command, you must specify the path to the .apk file that you want to install:"
To me, that meant I should use push to copy and install to install. I would have thought it would specify the "local path" if installed from my computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
adb shell pm install /mnt/sdcard/myAppName.apk
```

It will install apk from the device it self.
Please check `Package Manager` [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html).

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device and the from the location where you have your app.apk do `adb install app.apk` . It will install it to your device.